# Secure IoT device against remote access

Tags: linux, privacy, web-browser, firewalls

I'm developing an IoT device (a Raspberry Pi) that will be connected to the internet. It's users won't necessarily be comfortable with deploying updates, so I plan to make it as secure as possible without having to deploy updates every so often.

What the device has to be able to do:

- access a microphone: This is my concern, I do not want anyone to spy on the device's users by accessing the microphone remotely
- access specific APIs on the internet. They're known beforehand and can be considered save and non-changing. They will be accessed via command line, python or Chrome (see below)
- execute Python code
- run an instance of Chrome. It will be the most recent version when I create the device, but will (hopefully) never require to be updated
- run Raspian (Debian optimized for the Raspberry Pi). Will hopefully never require to be updated as well.

My current plan is to:

- Only communicate with the APIs using SSL
- Set the `/etc/hosts` to only allow communication with the specific IPs of the APIs I need to use

I do not worry about users of the device manipulating any settings. Attacks that require physical access to the device are not my concern.
Attacks that require to be close to the device are interesting, but highly unlikely (the device isn't wide-spread, it's not common knowledge where they're installed and the users are common people, no high security locations). I'm mostly worried about more or less random attacks via the internet.

Are there any additional steps that I should take to ensure that the device (especially the microphone access) is still secure even if there's a known bug in one of its software components?

Comment: you need to have to ability to push updates to it, otherwise you risk being in a position to order your customers to stop using a device if some part of a large stack is somehow compromised.

Comment: *"Set the /etc/hosts to only allow communication with the specific IPs of the APIs I need to use"* - this does not in any way restrict communication. All it does is set a mapping between specific hostnames and IP addresses. A firewall (like iptables) restricts access instead. Narrow routing to only specific hosts might restrict access. Using a VPN might control access too.

Comment: Why do you need to run chrome there?

Comment: @dandavis: Pushing might be difficult (the devices will use metered internet connections). The users will have to take them to a location with an available router and start the update themself. I will make this possible, but it's a hassle I'd like to avoid.
@SteffenUllrich: Thank you, that's a very good point. I misunderstood the meaning of `/etc/hosts/`. I will make sure to use a firewall to restrict external access to the specific IPs I need to use. Would you like to make this into an answer?

Comment: @Ángel: In my specific situation, one of the services I want to access requires me to use a JS-library that's optimized for Chrome. But I think a valid general usecase would be to use Chrome to show some page on a connected display.